# lexer for programming languages in rust

Tags: performance, rust, lexical-analysis

I'm relatively new to rust, so you don't need to go easy on the criticism.

right now, this lexes 1MB of text (well, trims a 1MB-long word) in 30ms.
is there any way I can make this faster?

## cursor.rs:

```rust
use std::str::Chars;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Cursor<'a> {
    peek: Option<char>,
    pub chars: Chars<'a>,
    pub pos: usize,
    pub row: usize,
    pub col: usize
}

impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    pub fn new(text: &'a str) -> Self {
        let mut chars = text.chars();
        Self {
            peek: chars.next(),
            chars,
            pos: 0,
            row: 1,
            col: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) -> Option<char> {
        let peek = self.peek?;
        if peek == '\n' {
            self.col = 1;
            self.row += 1;
        } else {
            self.col += 1;
        }
        self.pos += peek.len_utf8();
        self.peek = self.chars.next();
        Some(peek)
    }

    pub fn peek_is<F: FnOnce(char) -> bool>(&mut self, fun: F) -> bool {
        self.peek.map_or(false, fun)
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn peeking(&mut self, ch: char) -> bool {
        self.peek == Some(ch)
    }

    pub fn next_if<F: FnOnce(char) -> bool>(&mut self, fun: F) -> Option<char> {
        if self.peek_is(fun) {
            self.next()
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

## lexer.rs:

```rust
use crate::cursor::Cursor;

pub enum TokenKind<'a> {
    Ident(&'a str),
    Num(&'a str),
    Str(String)
}

pub struct Lexer<'a> {
    text: &'a str,
    pub cursor: Cursor<'a>
}

impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    pub fn new<T: Into<&'a str>>(text: T) -> Self {
        let text = text.into();
        Self {
            text,
            cursor: Cursor::new(text)
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn token<F: FnOnce(char) -> bool + Copy>(&mut self, fun: F) -> &'a str {
        let pos = self.cursor.pos;
        while self.cursor.peek_is(fun) {
            self.cursor.next();
        }
        &self.text[pos..self.cursor.pos]
    }

    pub fn trim_ident(&mut self) -> &'a str {
        self.token(|x| x.is_alphanumeric() || x == '_')
    }

    pub fn trim_integer(&mut self) -> &'a str {
        self.token(char::is_numeric)
    }
}

// impl<'a> Iterator for Lexer<'a> {
//     type Item = TokenKind<'a>;
//
//     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<TokenKind<'a>> {
//         todo!()
//     }
// }
```

## lib.rs:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

pub mod cursor;
pub mod lexer;
pub use lexer::*;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
}
```

## main.rs:

```rust
use scanner_rs::*;

macro_rules! time {
    ($name:literal, $($test:tt)*) => {
        {
            let start = std::time::Instant::now();
            $($test)*
            println!("{}: {:?}", $name, start.elapsed());
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let code = "H".repeat(104_857_6);
    let mut test_time = Lexer::new(&*code);
    time! {
        "init",
        Lexer::new(&*code);
    };
    time! {
        "next",
        lexer.cursor.next();
    };
    time! {
        "ident",
        println!("{}", lexer.trim_ident()); // HHHHHHHHHHHH...
    };
    let mut hello_world = Lexer::new("Hello");
    println!("{}", lexer.trim_ident()); // Hello
}
```

Comment: If you implement a `next` method on `Cursor`, you should do so by implementing the `Iterator` trait for it.

Comment: Is your lexer supposed to work with arbitrary Unicode, or only with ASCII? The latter vastly simplifies the operations...

Comment: unicode is supported by default in rust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus on performance, with general principles first.

#### Memory Allocations

You did well using an iterator over `str`, rather than allocating a `Vec<char>`. This avoids memory allocations, and that's generally a good thing.

On the other hand, your plan to use a `String` is `TokenKind` is not great. It would be better to just use a slice. If you plan to have potentially escaped characters, you can just add a variant for string-without-escaped-characters and string-with-escaped-characters. The goal is to defer the memory allocation as long as possible, and if possible to eschew it at the end too.

#### `char` is problematic.

From a pure performance point of view, `char` is fairly problematic. It may be *necessary*, mind, but it still is problematic.

The problem is that you turn a byte into a `char`, then query the `char`, and go back to the byte. From a performance point of view, you'd be better off operating on bytes altogether... although if you want to support Unicode it'll definitely makes things a tad harder.

#### Byte-wise segmentation is slow by design

Your algorithm is, at its core, operating one byte at a time. That is far from ideal.

The throughput of a lexer is typically expressed as the number of cycles it takes per byte, and the lower the better. You *can* try to fine-tune the operations performed on each byte to minimize this measure... but that's ignoring two important aspects of the CPU:

- ILP: Instruction Level Parallelism, which consists in performing multiple instructions "in parallel".
- SIMD: Same Instruction Multiple Data, which consists in performing a single instructions on multiple elements at once.

At the moment, a compiler *may* be able to turn your byte-by-byte algorithm into a vectorized version, or to unlock some ILP, but there are limits to the magic that a compiler is able to perform, and the `char` intermediary step is making your compiler's life difficult in the first place.

#### Back to the drawing board

What are you trying to do here? Lex a piece of *code*.

Code typically looks like:

- `3 * 4`
- `object.method(item, expr + ession)`

If you look closely, you'll realize that you have roughly 3 or 4 categories of characters:

- Identifiers & numbers.
- "Operators" & braces -- aka separators.
- Whitespace.

This is because you can view tokenization as a two-steps processes: Segmentation and Classification.

It's common for text-book lexers to mix the two together: peek at the first non-whitespace character, then parse a number/identifier/... based on it. It's simple, but not necessarily *efficient*.

If you split the process, you can first segment and *then* classify. And that's much more mechanically sympathetic.

So, taking `object.method(item, expr + ession)`:

- Segmentation is about splitting into `object`, `.`, `method`, `(`, `item`, `,`, `expr`, `+`, `ession`, and `)`.
- Classification is about assigning the kind: `object` is an identifier, `.` is (here) a method/field separator, ...

There's two difficulties here:

- Floating point numbers, and their pesky `.` and `-` in the middle of those numbers. The tokens can be reassembled in the parsing stage, or in an intermediate stage.
- Strings and comments, which require a "mode switch" regardless.

Fortunately, they are quite rarer than regular tokens.

Implementation-wise, the idea is to use an iterator on *chunks* of bytes and "mark" each as "identifier-like", whitespace, and other (operator, brace, quote, ...). Chunks of 64 bytes are great because `u64` is native on most architectures, even if 16-bytes or 32-bytes SIMD operations need to be used. On the `u64`, you'll be looking at operations identifying the next set/unset bit, which in Rust are `leading_zeros`, `leading_ones` or `trailing_zeros`, `trailing_ones` depending on the way you compose the mask.

Comment: how exactly would i implement this?

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxx: It depends if you want to use the intrinsics directly, use a library, or write "vectorizable" code and expect the compiler. In general, it's pretty much the same logic as for scalar: ranges are checked with >= and <=, equality with ==, just using SIMD operations.